# BNC connector schema pins

Tags: eaglecad, footprint, header, bnc

I am making a PCB using Eagle which features a few BNC connectors. Eagle comes with the RADIALL R141426161 component so I'll just use these instead of searching for other ones.

The component has the following schematic symbol and footprint

[image]

I see there are 5 pins on the footprint but only 2 on the schematic symbol. I assume one of the schematic pins corresponds to the central pin (signal?) on the footprint and the other to the 4 outer pins (ground?). Can someone clarify for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, the outer pins connect to the connector body, which is normally grounded. The intended connector would look something like this:

[image]

Though I have to say that straight BNC connectors are not so common.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Just to confirm the central pin on the symbol corresponds to the central pin on the footprint?

Comment: It looks like it would, but you can confirm that when you import your design to the PCB editor.